# Getting logged out of application when going through load balancer

Tags: weblogic

When a user logs into our applicaiton and then clicks a link in the application they are logged out and taken back to the login screen. Sometimes it takes a few link-clicks to get kicked back to the login screen. We are not sure why this is happening.

We believe that it might be that the user logs in to one weblogic server and then the load balancer is putting them the other weblogic server on a subsequent request and that server doesnt have the session information and thus their authentication information and kicks them back to the login screen. We are seeing BEA-000117 errors in the logs which in the docs say means that "A server with an older version of session data tried to corrupt the session data.".

When we dont go through the load balancer, but hit the weblogic server directly, we are able to stay logged in and dont get kicked back to the login screen. Which seems to indicate that the problem is localized to something going on between the load balancer and weblogic rather than something wrong with say session date replication and so forth. The load balancer is *supposed* to be configured to do sticky sessions properly but we have yet to be able to verify this.

Any ideas?

Note, our configuration is:

- We have a load balancer in front of a 2-server weblogic cluster
- One application (bundled as an ear of many wars) is deployed to the cluster
- replicate_if_clustered is turned on in the weblogic.xml file (we have not tried turning this off)
- When we hit the

Comment: Do you have any web server between the LB and the WL cluster? Are you using the WLProxy plugin or similar for load balancing?

Comment: No web server between LB and WL cluster. I believe the LB is configured to inject its own cookie using the set-cookie2 directive to managed the sticky sesion.

Answer (score 2):

Enable sticky sessions on the load balancer so that all requests from the user are serviced by the same instance on the app-tier. The setting varies by the type of load balancer you are using.